# 2018: ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

Recently (17 sept 2018) I've got very surprised with following error while uploading ios app:

> ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New
>   iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display
>   on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the
>   Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to
>   {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the
>   top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you
>   localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app
>   launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at
>   https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen."

Launch images in app are in Assets and there were no such problems before for few years! Last successful build was 14 sept 2018. I wonder how this outdated (5-6 years) requirement could happen in fall of 2018?! Did somebody else get this issue recently?

Comment: I have this issue now, it came completely out of the blue. I'm totally stumped. How did you get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The LaunchScreen file must be called 'LaunchScreen.storyboard', regardless of whether you have specified a name in the plist. Whilst changing the name in the plist will show the correct launch screen, it wont pass this poorly written check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check size of your images with the official Apple page.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Also I would suggest you to use LaunchStoryboard instead of launch image per each device.
In this way you will avoid mess with missed images for some devices.

You can use one image or even apply some layout for launch screen.

https://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Comment: He is not using launch images. He is using a LaunchScreen storyboard.

Comment: He doesn't use LaunchStoryboard if you would read question
"Launch images in app are in Assets and there were no such problems before for few years"